Turing degree of group isomorphism problem
The group isomorphism problem of a finitely presentd group is undecidable. But where is the problem embedded in the arithmetical hierarchy, i. e. what is the Turing degree?

The isomorphism problem for finitely presented groups is $\Sigma_1$-complete.
The proof of undecidability in fact encodes the halting problem: we produce, for each $k$, a pair of finitely presented groups $A_k, B_k$ such that $A_k\cong B_k\iff k\in\emptyset'$. This gives $\Sigma_1$-hardness.
In the opposite direction, suppose $A=(G; R), B=(H;S)$ are finitely presented groups (here $G,H$ are the finite generating sets and $R,S$ are the finite sets of relations). The existence of an isomoprhism $A\cong B$ is equivalent to the existence of a pair of finite functions $f:G\rightarrow H^*, g:H\rightarrow G^*$ (where ${}^*$ is Kleene star) and "proofs" (= appropriate applications of the $R$- and $S$-relations) that $f\circ g=id_H$ and  $g\circ f=id_G$ and that the $R/S$-relations hold after applying $f/g$. The key point is that such a pair (and verification) is just a finite amount of data; so the existence of such a pair is $\Sigma_1$.
